# Enable nested virtualization on Windows 10 guest, Ubuntu 18.04 host, AMD Ryzen

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, docker, hyper-v, linux-kvm

I have a AMD Ryzen 1700 on Ubuntu 18.04. I have installed a Windows 10 guest under KVM using virt-manager. To be able to do that with the right CPU type ("EPYC" or "EPYC-IBPB"), I had to apply the workaround described [here](https://www.redhat.com/archives/vfio-users/2018-May/msg00007.html) ("`options kvm ignore_msrs=1`").

Now I'd like to experiment with Docker on the Windows 10 guest.  It requires a functioning Hyper-V install.  Unfortunately the Hyper-V hypervisor cannot be installed because *"The processor does not have second level access translation (SLAT) capabilities"*.

Weirdly, on a Windows 7 guest I *do* seem to have nested virtualization enabled (but the Docker Desktop Client only supports Windows 10).

What could be the cause here?